# Changing the starting point of an excerpt in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Each of my posts starts with `<ul class="toc_post_list">` where I have Table of Contests. The problem is that the table of contests is displaying as excerpt whenever the excerpt is being called, regardless of template.

I thought I might do a workaround to skip the ul class and set the first `<p>` after `<ul>` as the expert, but my code is not working.

Here is what I've tried:

```
// Function to modify the excerpt
function custom_excerpt($excerpt) {
global $post;

// Check if the current post has a manual excerpt set
if ($post->post_excerpt) {
    return $excerpt;
} else {
    // If no manual excerpt is set, get the content and find the first <p> tag
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
    $excerpt = '';

    // Exclude content inside <ul class="toc_post_list">
    $pattern = '/<ul\sclass="toc_post_list">(.*?)<\/ul>/s';
    $content_without_toc = preg_replace($pattern, '', $content);

    // Use regex to find the first <p> tag after excluding the specified content
    preg_match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/', $content_without_toc, $matches);

    if ($matches) {
        $excerpt = $matches[0];
    }

    return $excerpt;
 }
}

// Apply the custom excerpt function to the 'get_the_excerpt' and 'the_excerpt' filter hooks
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
```

Any ideas why my function doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I refined the custom WordPress excerpt function to exclude a specific `<ul>` class and fetch the first `<p>` element as the excerpt, while ensuring compatibility with varied HTML structures and applying necessary content filters. Try below

```
function custom_excerpt($excerpt) {
    global $post;

    // Check if the current post has a manual excerpt set
    if ($post->post_excerpt) {
        return $excerpt;
    } else {
        // Get the content and apply filters
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

        // Exclude content inside <ul class="toc_post_list">
        $pattern = '/<ul\s+class="toc_post_list">.*?<\/ul>/s';
        $content_without_toc = preg_replace($pattern, '', $content);

        // Use regex to find the first <p> tag after excluding the specified content
        preg_match('/<p>.*?<\/p>/s', $content_without_toc, $matches);

        if (!empty($matches)) {
            $excerpt = strip_tags($matches[0]);
        }

        return $excerpt;
    }
}

// Apply the custom excerpt function to the 'get_the_excerpt' and 'the_excerpt' filter hooks
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
```